# Scheduling GPU in cloud for training deep learning models

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, cloud

There are people having their own cloud VM instances to do their task. Currently we can attach GPU when we want to train our deep learning model. But I have only 1-2 GPU that I can use at a time. So, I want to build a scheduling mechanism that will start training my model once the GPU is free. How can we do the same?
One solution might be making a VM instance with attached GPU and we send request to that instance from other instances to schedule my job. Is it feasible and how to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a GPU instance based on the availability of the GPU resources in a particular zone, there is no such visibility for the user to observe GCP resources are available or stock out.

You can schedule a cron job on an instance that will execute the task on the instance having GPU resources by impersonating service account [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#impersonating_a_service_account). For example, you can run the below mentioned command to create a new file on the ‘GPU_INSTANCE_NAME’ instance by impersonating the service account of the instance. At this moment, create a script containing the below mentioned command and use cron job to schedule the task as per your requirement.

“ gcloud compute ssh GPU_INSTANCE_NAME --project=Project_Name --zone=VM_Zone --impersonate-service-account=Instance_Service_Account --command="touch newfile" ”

Comment: No, There are GPUs available in my zone but I want to use only 1 GPU at a time. So, I want to figure out a way for that.

Comment: To create instance having 1 GPU and you are able to schedule the job by putting the gcloud command in the bash script. However, if you want gcloud command to create an instance, you just need to follow the article  or click on the create instance on GUI mode then configure your instance with 1 GPU and simply copy the equivalent command line at the bottom of the page. Then put the script in the cron job in order to scheduling the instance as per your requirement.

Comment: [article](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create)

Comment: But I want to schedule gpu as per vm requirement.

Comment: If you want to schedule VM, you can use GCP cloud scheduler in order to stop and start the VMs but there is no option for schedule GPU at this moment. For more information please [click](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/save-money-by-stopping-and-starting-compute-engine-instances-on-schedule) here